# Scala - Play 2.1 - Swagger: compiles fine, doesn't work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, swagger

I'm currently documenting a Play 2.1 application with Swagger. I've managed to have it compiling successfully but it doesn't show any information on the resulting JSON.

localhost:9000/api-docs.json

```
{
  apiVersion: "0.1",
  swaggerVersion: "1.1",
  basePath: "http://localhost:9000"
}
```

localhost:9000/api-docs.json/items

```
{
  code: 500,
  message: "api listing for path /api-docs.json/items not found",
  type: "unknown"
}
```

This is the annotation for the controller object:

```
@Api(value = "/items", listingPath = "/api-docs.{format}/items", description = "Operations about Items")
object ItemController extends Controller {
```

These are the annotations for a controller method:

```
  @ApiOperation(value = "Gets the item of a specific ID", notes = "Returns an Item", responseClass = "Item", httpMethod = "GET")
  @ApiErrors(Array(
    new ApiError(code = 400, reason = "Invalid ID supplied"),
    new ApiError(code = 404, reason = "Item not found")))
  def get(@ApiParam(value="Id of the Item to Fetch")@PathParam("id") id: Long) = Action{ request => controller.get(id: Long) }
```

These are the required configurations on application.conf:

```
api.version="0.1"
swagger.api.basepath="http://localhost:9000"
#swagger.security.filter="security.AuthorizationFilter"
```

The code shown above follows Swagger's documentation provided sample application. Do you know of any working example on Play 2.1? Any clues on what's wrong or what's missing?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: routes file portion:

```
GET     /api-docs.json                 controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
GET     /api-docs.json/items           controllers.ApiHelpController.getResource(path = "/api-docs.json/items")
```

Comment: Could you provide the routes file as well?

Comment: I have a working 2.1 Swagger implementation. Your implementation looks Ok except for the `responseClass` that I think needs the FQN, `responseClass="some.package.Item"`. Also could you show the routes part for the `ItemController.get` method.

Comment: The module will log a *warning* if the `responseClass` is incorrect

Comment: Did you add the controller to the routes file? `GET /items/:id controllers.ItemController.get(id)`

Answer (score 0):

the sample in swagger-core for play2 works fine with play 2.1:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/scala_2.10.0/samples/scala-play2

See that you have the latest swagger-play2 module:

> val appDependencies: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = Seq(
>       "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.2.4"   )

which lives in maven central

Answer (score 0):

```
GET     /api-docs.json/items           controllers.ApiHelpController.getResource(path = "/api-docs.json/items")
```

should be

```
GET     /api-docs.json/items           controllers.ApiHelpController.getResource(path = "/items")
```